# I have a GUI in Java, I do not know how to proceed

Tags: java

I need to mount a screen with information that I searched for from the database.
For this I searched the information and stored in an `ArrayList`. I need to use a `for`loop to go through the `ArrayList` and each loop to mount a `JTextArea`.

I tried to make the `for` loop to go through the `ArrayList` and go mounting the screen but I could not do anything.

Screen code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TelaSugestao extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}

   private JTextArea txtArea;

   private Sugestao sugestao;
   private Connection conn;

   public TelaSugestao(Connection conn) {
      super("Tela sugestao");

      txtArea = new JTextArea(3,3);

      this.conn = conn;

      Container caixa = getContentPane();
      caixa.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      caixa.add(txtArea);

      setSize(432,400);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   // Trying to mount the screen every time the For runs the ArrayList.
   public void montaTela() {
      Sugestao sugestao = new Sugestao(); 
      ArrayList<Sugestao> listaSugestao = sugestao.carregaSugestao(conn);
      for (int i = 0; i < listaSugestao.size(); i++) {

      }
   }
}
```

I'm looking for the database information this way:

```
public ArrayList<Sugestao> carregaSugestao(Connection conn) {
    String sqlSelect = "Select id, sugestao from tabelaTeste where id_sugestao = ?";
    ArrayList<Sugestao> listaSugestao = new ArrayList<>();

    try (PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelect);) {
        stm.setInt(1, getIdSugestao());
        try (ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();) {
            while (rs.next()){
                Sugestao s = new Sugestao();
                s.setIdSugestao(rs.getInt("id_sugestao"));
                s.setSugestao(rs.getString("sugestao")); 
                listaSugestao.add(s);
                guardaSugestao = carregaSugestao(conn);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.print(e1.getStackTrace());
    }
    return listaSugestao;
}
```

Could you please explain how to do this?

Comment: you want a new textarea for every object in your arraylist? or do you want to write text contained in your array list to the textare?

Comment: This is a textarea for every object my arraylist contains
Google translator, sorry

Answer (score 0):

remove these 2 line from your constructor: `txtArea = new JTextArea(3,3); caixa.add(txtArea);`  method now changes to:

```
 public void montaTela(Container pane){
      Sugestao sugestao = new Sugestao(); 
      ArrayList<Sugestao> listaSugestao = sugestao.carregaSugestao(conn);
      for(int i = 0; i < listaSugestao.size(); i++){
         txtArea=new JTextArea();
         //add Text to your txtArea with .append(string)
         pane.add(txtarea);
      }
   }
```

and call the method with: `montaTela(caixa)` <-- requires to be called in constructor. otherwise make a getter for the content pane

Comment: My database contains 5 suggestions, these 5 suggestions that I searched and stored in ArrayList, I would like to put each one in a different TextArea so I tried to use For to go through the ArrayList and so each loop makes a different screen. But I tried and I could not.
Google translator, sorry

Comment: at least i now know what you want to do